# Batch File - Commands not executing after Powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have written simple batch script to replace some text in a file, when executed via command line but when those commands are copied to .bat file execution stops after powershell command. Any idea how to execute powershell commands in batch file?

[image]

Comment: You just call `powershell.exe` with no parameters so it starts an interactive session. If you were to type `exit` your batch script would continue. Use the `-command` switch to execute whatever it is you want to. And please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32048332/edit) your question and include the code there

Comment: Thanks arco444 for replying I tried that as well. You can see there is REM line with -command followed by replace code.

Comment: When executed powershell.exe -command Get-Content AssemblyInfo.cs | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'assembly: AssemblyVersion', 'assembly11111' } | Set-Content AssemblyInfo2.cs got error 'ForEach-Object' is not recognized

Comment: You need to put the powershell command in quotes. i.e. `powershell -command "get-content file.cs"`

Comment: That worked. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 0):

arco444's answer worked for me in comments:

You just call powershell.exe with no parameters so it starts an interactive session. If you were to type exit your batch script would continue. Use the -command switch to execute whatever it is you want to. And please edit your question and include the code there. Also You need to put the powershell command in quotes. i.e. powershell -command "get-content file.cs"